# How to detect redirected URL in cordova inappbrowser and close browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using the cordova inappbrowser for my ionic app. I need to detect when url redirects to `http://xx.success.html 
or 
http://xx.failure.html`

my code:

```
public openWithCordovaBrowser(url: string) {
    //where are events triggered (_self,_blank,_window)?
    let target = "_self"; 

    let inAppBrowserObject = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, target, this.inAppBrowserOptions);

                //When the page is success, close inappbrowser
    if (inAppBrowserObject.on('loadstart').subscribe) {
      inAppBrowserObject.on('loadstart').subscribe((e: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
        if (e && e.url) {
          if (e.url.includes('success.html')) {
            inAppBrowserObject.close(); //not reached?
          }
        }
      });
    }

               //When the InAppBrowser is closed, check and use the last viewed URL
    if (inAppBrowserObject.on('exit').subscribe) {
      inAppBrowserObject.on('exit').subscribe((e: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
        if (url) {
        console.log('exit: ' + e); //this is reached
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

doesn't work and `inAppBrowserObject.close()` never gets called.

error in chrome dev console:

```
Error in Success callbackId: InAppBrowser780208391 : TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
cordova.js:310 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at InAppBrowserObject.close (vendor.js:81063)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (main.js:411)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (vendor.js:20899)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (vendor.js:20846)
    at Subscriber._next (vendor.js:20786)
    at Subscriber.next (vendor.js:20750)
    at Channel.fire (cordova.js:843)
    at InAppBrowser._eventHandler (inappbrowser.js:48)
    at cb (inappbrowser.js:108)
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:291)
```

But closing the browser calls `console.log('exit: ' + e);`

my inAppBrowser object look like so:
[image]

Comment: Could you post the output for nAppBrowserObject.on('loadstart') ?

Comment: added the debug output

Answer (score 4):

this is a cordova plugin issue.
[Issue link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2918)

---

I removed cordova and npm plugins 5.x.x and installed 4.20.0. That solved the problem.

remove old versions:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm uninstall @ionic-native/in-app-browser --save
```

install 4.20.0 version:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser@4.20.0
```

---

also import changed from

```
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'
```

to

```
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this solution working well with cordova 8 and ionic 3.20.. Would you need a .show to be invoked. Seems to be related to the screen never being in .show status - maybe? If your browser is hidden by default.

```
  const iabrowser = this.inAppBrowser.create(this.signupUrl,'_self',iabOptions);

  this.loader.presentLoading();
    iabrowser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event =>{
    console.log(event);
    iabrowser.executeScript({code: "alert('loadstart! I am an alert box!!')"});
    if (event && event.url) {
        if (event.url.includes('/app/main/login')) {
            iabrowser.close();
        }
    }
    iabrowser.show();
  });
  iabrowser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event =>{
    console.log(event);
    this.loader.dismissLoading();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are referring two distinct instances here. Try with target as '_blank'. Cordova documentation says:

**_self:** Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

**_blank:** Opens in the InAppBrowser.

Reference: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/